# How GCC/OS handle the uncaught exception?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

What happens there is an uncaught exception in c++? Shall the OS handle the behavior or the compiler(in my case is GCC) should?

For example: `throw std::exception();` or `throw std::runtime_error();`

Comment: the compiler does not handle any exceptions in your software. Compiler only compiles your code the the asm or object file.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I means the std libs implementation within the compiler.

Comment: it is not part of the compiler